# Synchronization doesnt quite work

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization

I have the following code which I'm trying to write a LRU Cache. I have a runner class that I'm running against random capacity of the cache. However, Cache size is exceeding it is capacity. When I make the FixLRU method synchronized, it becomes more accurate when the cache size is more than 100 however it gets slower. When I remove the synchronized keyword, cache is becoming less accurate.

Any ideas how to make this work properly? more accurate?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public abstract class Cache<TKey, TValue> implements ICache<TKey,TValue>{

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<TKey,TValue> _cache;

    protected Cache()
    {
        _cache=  new ConcurrentHashMap<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    protected Cache(int capacity){
        _cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void Put(TKey key, TValue value) {
        _cache.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public TValue Get(TKey key) {
        TValue value = _cache.get(key);

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void Delete(TKey key) {
        _cache.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void Purge() {
        for(TKey key : _cache.keySet()){
            _cache.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public void IterateCache(){

        for(TKey key: _cache.keySet()){
            System.out.println("key:"+key+" , value:"+_cache.get(key));
        }

    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _cache.size();
    }


}


import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class LRUCache<TKey,TValue> extends Cache<TKey,TValue> implements ICache<TKey, TValue> {

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TKey> _queue;
    private int capacity;
    public LRUCache(){
        _queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TKey>();
    }

    public LRUCache(int capacity){
        this();
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Put(TKey key, TValue value)
    { 
        FixLRU(key);

        super.Put(key, value);  
    }

    private void FixLRU(TKey key)
    {
        if(_queue.contains(key))
        {
            _queue.remove(key);
            super.Delete(key);
        }

        _queue.offer(key);

        while(_queue.size() > capacity){
            TKey keytoRemove =_queue.poll();
            super.Delete(keytoRemove);
        }
    }

    public TValue Get(TKey key){

        TValue _value = super.Get(key);

        if(_value == null){
            return null;
        }

        FixLRU(key);

        return _value;
    }

    public void Delete(TKey key){

        super.Delete(key);
    }

}

public class RunningLRU extends Thread{

    static LRUCache<String, String> cache = new LRUCache<String, String>(50);

    public static void main(String [ ] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Thread t1 = new RunningLRU();
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new RunningLRU();
        t2.start();
        Thread t3 = new RunningLRU();
        t3.start();
        Thread t4 = new RunningLRU();
        t4.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(cache.toString());
        cache.IterateCache();
        System.out.println(cache.Count());

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
            cache.Put("test"+i, "test"+i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using synchronized (capacity) { //code } around main block of FixLRU method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would clean up additional entries after adding your entry.  This minimises the time that the cache will be larger than you wanted.  You can also trigger size() to perform a cleanup.

> Any ideas how to make this work properly?

Does your test reflect how your application behaves?  It may be that the cache behaves properly (or much closer to it) when you have not hammering it. ;)

If this test does reflect your application behaviour then perhaps an LRUCache is not the best choice.

Comment: it works fine when i m not hammmering it, ie: single threaded. when i used synch. method to fix the backing queue, it works fine too, but then it gets slower, when i remove synch. keyword from the method, cache size exceeds it s capacity.

Comment: If you clean up at the end of your `put()`, how bad is it?  Given your capacity is likely to be arbitrary, how much of a problem is this?

Comment: it s random as you would guess. I just want it to be precise. I am using concurrent collections but still having these issues. If i m using concurrent collections and i d use synchronized keyword, then what s the point? right.

Comment: You can have it precise OR you can have it fast. For me the whole point of having a cache is whether it improves performance or not. I assume nothing in your program will fail because the size is 103 instead of 100. If so, make the maximum size slightly lower. BTW You need to `synchronized` the get size method as well to see the right size each time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that you aren't using the special *synchronized* version of the put method [`putIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29). If you don't use it, a `ConcurrentHashMap` behaves as if *not* synchronized - like a normal Map eg HashMap.

When you use it, you must continue to use only the *returned* value, so your `Put()` method doesn't have the correct signature (it should return `TValue`) to support concurrency. You'll need to redesign your interface.

Also, in java land, unlike .Net land, we name our methods with a leading lowercase, eg `put()`, not `Put()`. It would behove you to rename your methods thus.